# Pass Parameterized md-date-locale attibute to md-datepicker in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, wai-aria, angularjs-material

I am trying to pass JSON string to **md-datepicker** directive as below:

```
md-date-locale="{ msgOpenCalendar: 'Open calendar for {{parameter.name}}' }"
```

**md-date-locale** attribute is rendered as:

```
md-date-locale="{ msgOpenCalendar: 'Open calendar for Start Date' }"
```

But, the **aria-label** for open calendar button as:

```
aria-label="Open calendar for {{parameter.name}}"
```

I need the aria-label to be rendered as **'Open calendar for Start Date'**.

Can anyone please suggest? Or is it a bug in **md-datepicker** directive?

Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double-curly braces in your view, do the concatenation in your controller instead:

```
$scope.msgOpenCalendarText = "Open calendar for Start Date " + $scope.parameter.name;
```

Then define your attribute like so:

```
md-date-locale="{ msgOpenCalendar: msgOpenCalendarText }"
```

Comment: Assigning msgOpenCalendarText to $rootScope and putting its value between single quote as below worked for me:
$rootScope.msgOpenCalendarText = "'" + "Open calendar for " + $scope.parameter.name + "'";
 md-date-locale="{ msgOpenCalendar: msgOpenCalendarText }"

Please update your answer for rootScope and to include single quotes, so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid using rootScope unless absolutely needed. If you are having to use rootScope for this, then it’s a sign you may have other problems with your setup. You really should post all the relevant code, including your controller definition